# selenium webdriver using firefox for google search/selenium testing

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open google.com first then type "selenium testing".

I only wanted to use `className` for webdriver using eclipse but I am getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" 
   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: 
   {"method":"class name","selector":"Tg7LZd"}
   Command duration or timeout: 37 milliseconds
```

Here is my code:

```java
package coreJava;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Training1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.className("gLFyf")).sendKeys("selenium testing");     
        driver.findElement(By.className("Tg7LZd")).click();
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"Tg7LZd"}
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** was unable to find any element as per the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) you have used.

Your main issue is the **classNames** you have used are based on [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) and are generated **dynamically** which we can't guess before they are generated. 
As an alternative you can use the following solution:

```
package coreJava;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Training1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));  
        myElement.sendKeys("selenium testing");
        myElement.submit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver");
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("https://google.com");
Thread.sleep(3);

driver.findElement(By.className("gsfi")).sendKeys("selenium testing");
Thread.sleep(3);

driver.findElement(By.className("sbqs_c")).click();
Thread.sleep(3);

driver.close();
```

> This is working code

.
These will open the google chrome and then write "selenium testing" in search box and then search it using the class.